# How can I download an age-restricted YouTube video to my computer, free of charge?

Tags: youtube

[This is the video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=sCyyshL4Qm4&has_verified=1). None of these websites helped.

I don't know any programming. Thus [youtube-dl](https://www.reddit.com/r/answers/comments/79nqi2/youtube_downloader_that_was_able_download_deleted/dp3xzmg/) looks too complicated.

[ClipConverter](https://www.clipconverter.cc/error?videoid=318657645&errorstr=ClipConverter+is+not+available+for+videos+containing+music.)

[image]

[Hooktube](https://www.reddit.com/r/Piracy/comments/7nmtod/can_i_download_age_restricted_videos_from_youtube/ds3g1s7/) offers to convert only to .mp3.

[image]

Comment: On Firefox, I have the free Video Downloader Professional add-on installed.  The video was readily downloadable.  There doesn't seem to be any age restriction or issue, and nothing special was required.  It isn't clear why you're having a problem.

Comment: What makes this off-topic?  According to the Super User topic list (link above): Super User is about "computer software," and "personal and home computer networking."  This question is marginally about personal networking (downloading videos from the internet), and is most definitely about software (specifically, which software to download videos).  And it's a question that many many people will have.  So why close it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://download.cnet.com/YouTube-PlayList-Downloader/3000-2071_4-76161216.html) is a good application from CNet; it has no viruses and is quite effective at doing so. It is Windows-only and has a nice GUI and can convert to multiple formats.

youtube-dl, however is a great tool to download age-restricted material. youtube-dl is only for the command line, however. It isn't platform-specific, however, so you can install it on Windows and macOS. You need the Python interpreter (2.6-2.7 or 3.2+) to run youtube-dl. The syntax, once you get it installed is this:

```
youtube-dl <website you want to download from>
```

For Debian and Ubuntu-based distos, it is available in the regular repositories. Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

For Fedora and CentOS (make sure the epel repository is enabled), use:

```
sudo yum install youtube-dl
```

There is a .exe with a wizard from the official website (not the GitHub page) for Windows command lines.